# Comparing struts ognl value to scriptlet value in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts, ognl

I have to compare this to a value like below:

```
${page_id } ---- <% out.print(a); %>

<c:if test="${page_id != a}">
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you give some more context? I do not understand the question at all...

Answer (score 3):

Presuming that "a" is a scriptlet variable.
El expressions map to page/request/session/application attributes in scope.

${page_id} is approximately equivalent to pageContext.findAttribute("page_id");

To be able to compare them, you need to get them into the same space.
One way of doing this is with scriptlet code:

```
<% pageContext.setAttribute("a", a); %>
```

You should now be able to access ${a} as an EL expression.
Not a preferred solution, as it uses scriptlet code (something to avoid in JSPs)
There might be a better way of course. It all depends on where the value of "a" come from in the first place.